# Javascript code containing alert is not working in Php

Tags: php

Alert line code is not working as I want to show alert on particular condition but code die after that and alert is also not showing. please tell the solution for this.

```
case "NEW_REC_INSTANCE_PRIPB":    
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['PRIADCTG']) && !empty($_REQUEST['SEC_CD']) && !empty($_REQUEST['MATCODE']) && empty($_REQUEST['CLIENT_ADD'])) {
        $data = array();
        $qRSet = $objComm->GET_QUICK_RESULT("SELECT NVL (address_required, 'N') ADDE_REQ FROM " . $_SESSION['DB_USER'] . ".ad_ccpctg WHERE priadctg = '" . $_REQUEST['PRIADCTG'] . "' AND priccpctg = '" . $_REQUEST['SEC_CD'] . "' AND secccpctg = '" . $_REQUEST['MATCODE'] . "'  
    AND status = 'Y'", 1);
        IF ($qRSet['ADDE_REQ'] == 'Y') {

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Client address is required to enter! please check");</script>';
            if (!file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/DS/ccpentry_new/AS_PHP/uploadfile/DAA.txt', $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'])) {
                echo 'unable to write';
                die;
            }
            $data['ADD_REQ'] = $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'];
        } else {
            $data['ADD_REQ'] = $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'];
        }
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['actype'] == "FIRST_NEW_REC") {
        $newRecInsDet = $objGbl->SET_PUBL_NEWREC_INSTANCE($_REQUEST, "FY");
    } else if ($_REQUEST['actype'] == "NEW_REC") {
        $newRecInsDet = $objGbl->SET_PUBL_NEWREC_INSTANCE($_REQUEST, "Y");
    } else {
        $newRecInsDet = $objGbl->savePubData($_REQUEST, '', "", 1, $_REQUEST['INSNUM']);
    }

    echo json_encode($newRecInsDet);
    exit;
    break;
```

Comment: Turn off Caps Lock.

Comment: Writing in all caps is the equivalent of screaming. It's not nice to scream at people. Specially when you're asking them to help you. It's also harder to read text written in all caps. You should also indent your code properly.

Comment: @u_mulder.. Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please tell me the solution for the above problem.

Comment: why did you add ** with echo alert line. is there any particular reason I put that line in my code without ** and it works! https://prnt.sc/qcw5cg

Comment: @Amit Sharma.. No I haven't put it on code, it is just to highlight it.

Comment: okay please add the code from where you are sending these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case "NEW_REC_INSTANCE_PRIPB":    
$new_array = array();
if (!empty($_REQUEST['PRIADCTG']) && !empty($_REQUEST['SEC_CD']) && !empty($_REQUEST['MATCODE']) && empty($_REQUEST['CLIENT_ADD'])) {
    $data = array();
    $qRSet = $objComm->GET_QUICK_RESULT("SELECT NVL (address_required, 'N') ADDE_REQ FROM " . $_SESSION['DB_USER'] . ".ad_ccpctg WHERE priadctg = '" . $_REQUEST['PRIADCTG'] . "' AND priccpctg = '" . $_REQUEST['SEC_CD'] . "' AND secccpctg = '" . $_REQUEST['MATCODE'] . "' AND status = 'Y'", 1);
    IF ($qRSet['ADDE_REQ'] == 'Y') {
        $new_array['success'] = false;
        $new_array['error'] = 'Client address is required to enter! please check';

        if (!file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/DS/ccpentry_new/AS_PHP/uploadfile/DAA.txt', $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'])) {
            echo 'unable to write';
            die;
        }
        $data['ADD_REQ'] = $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'];
    } else {
        $data['ADD_REQ'] = $qRSet['ADDE_REQ'];
    }
}
if ($_REQUEST['actype'] == "FIRST_NEW_REC") {
    $new_array['success'] = true;
    $new_array['data'] = $objGbl->SET_PUBL_NEWREC_INSTANCE($_REQUEST, "FY");
} else if ($_REQUEST['actype'] == "NEW_REC") {
    $new_array['success'] = true;
    $new_array['data'] =$objGbl->SET_PUBL_NEWREC_INSTANCE($_REQUEST, "Y");
} else {
    $new_array['success'] = true;
    $new_array['data'] = $objGbl->savePubData($_REQUEST, '', "", 1, $_REQUEST['INSNUM'])

}

echo json_encode($new_array);
exit;
break;
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that they added the `**` for us to highlight where the issue is located. (As the question first contained _"Highlighted code is not working..."_ before they updated the question and removed the `**` as well)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson.. No I actually want to bold the code here..but they converted it to **.. It is actually not used by me in the code. I only want to highlight my my code so that other people can easily see it.

Comment: @sharmishtha - How is that not what I said? The `**` was there for highlighting where the issue is located, regardless if the intent was to bold the text or not.  (You can't format using markdown when you're inside a code block.)

Comment: @sharmishtha you are sending data using ajax and expected a json response. first you need to remove both exit;  break; and you can use die; then you can send data from here and use alert in your ajax

Comment: @AmitSharma - They most likely need the break though since the code seems to be inside a `switch/case`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay but if it is ajax then alert is not going to work here

Comment: @AmitSharma.. ok So can you tell me any other solution for this as I have to show here a error popup.

Comment: are you sending data using Ajax ?